# confidence interval in GLMM

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval

I would like to generate the values of the confidence interval for some explanatory variables of the response variable (called HUNTED). The data is about 3 distinct time PERIODS. 
However, when I use the code:
     library(MASS)
    confint(allspecies4)
I only get error messages (see below). Would anyone know how to improve my script so that I can access the confidence interval?
Obs.: My dataset is too large, I've just added a part of it so you can understand how its distribution is.

```
allspecies4<-read.csv(file= "dadosGLMM.csv", header= TRUE, sep= ";" )
attach(allspecies4)
library(lme4)
allspecies4<- glmer(HUNTED~ eco+TrophicLevel+age+ log(body_mass)+
                      habitat+ABUND + PERIOD + tabu +(1|Specie),
                    data=dadosGLMM, family=binomial)

library(MASS)
confint(allspecies4)


library(MASS)
> confint(allspecies4)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
Error in zeta(shiftpar, start = opt[seqpar1][-w]) : 
  profiling detected new, lower deviance
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
2: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
3: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
4: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
5: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
6: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
7: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
8: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
9: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-monotonic profile for (Intercept)
```

Sample data

```
 Specie body_mass TrophicLevel age eco habitat PERIOD HUNTED ABUND tabu
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  57   2       F DURING      0     2    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  57   2       F  AFTER      0     3    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  57   2       F BEFORE      0     4    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  67   2       F DURING      1     2    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  67   2       F  AFTER      0     2    1
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  53   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  74   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  30   2       S DURING      0     4    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  63   2       S DURING      0     4    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  54   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  30   2       S DURING      0     4    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  30   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  24   3       F DURING      0     3    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  24   3       F BEFORE      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  33   3       F  AFTER      1     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  33   3       F BEFORE      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  33   3       F DURING      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  43   3       F BEFORE      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  43   3       F DURING      0     4    0
```

Comment: You could also give a try in package **GLMMadaptive** (https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/). In particular, have a look in the vignette: https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#detailed-output-confidence-intervals-and-covariance-matrix-of-the-mles